# Does it make sense for dataloader enumerating to take 50% of the CPU and GPU time?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-dataloader

When I use torch.profiler to profile fit_one_epoch, I see dataloader enumeration takes more than 50% of the time. Setting pin_memory=True or num_workers>0 for initializing DataLoader does not reduce the percentage of time cost. Could someone please help? [image]

```python
    class NNModelTrainer:
        def __init__(self, model, optimizer, loss_func, n_epoch, batch_size, train_dataset, test_dataset):
            DEVICE = torch.device('cuda')
            self.model = model
            self.optimizer = optimizer
            self.loss_func = loss_func
            self.remaining_epochs = n_epoch
        
            self.train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
            self.test_dataset = test_dataset
        
        def fit_one_epoch(self):
            train_loss_val = 0
            self.model = self.model.to(DEVICE)
            self.model.train(mode=True)
                
            for x, y in self.train_dataloader:
                x, y = x.to(DEVICE), y.to(DEVICE)
                self.optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=False)
                yhat = self.model(x)
                train_loss = self.loss_func(yhat, y.squeeze(1)) * len(yhat)
                train_loss_val += train_loss.item()
                train_loss.backward()
                self.optimizer.step()
        
            self.remaining_epochs -= 1
```

Comment: Sure, this could definitely be the case. It depends on how complex / large your data examples are, how much pre-processing you do, whether your dataset caches the examples in memory or not, and how relatively complex your training pass is.

Comment: In the typical case, you train once, then predict many times, so the cost of the training is amortized over the total execution time.